# Stacked barchart, independent fill order for each stack

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm facing a behaviour of `ggplot2`, ordering and stacked barplot that I cannot understand.
 I've read some question about it ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345923/how-to-control-ordering-of-stacked-bar-chart-using-identity-on-ggplot2),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693075/using-ggplot2-how-can-i-set-the-order-of-a-stacked-bar-chart-by-the-value-of-on) and so on), but unluckily I cannot find a solution that suits to me. Maybe the answer is easy and I cannot see it. Hope it's not a dupe.

My main goal is to have each stack ordered independently, based on the ordering column (called here `ordering`).

Here I have some data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dats <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                   value = c(9,6,4,5,6,4,3,4,5),
                   ordering = c(1,2,3,2,3,1,3,2,4),
                   filling = c('a','b','c','b','a','a','c','d','b')) %>% arrange(id,ordering)
```

So there is an ID, a value, a value to use to order, and a filling, the data are as they should be ordered in the plot, as looking the `ordering` column.

I tried to plot it: the idea is to plot as a stacked barchart with x axis the `id`, the value `value`, filled by `filling`, but the filling has as order the value of `ordering`, in an ascending ordering, *i.e. biggest value of* `ordering` *at the bottom for each column*. The ordering of the `filling` is somewhat equal as the dataset, i.e. each column has an independent order.

As you can imagine those are fake data, so the number of id can vary.

```
 id value ordering filling
1  1     9        1       a
2  1     6        2       b
3  1     4        3       c
4  2     5        2       b
5  2     6        3       a
6  3     4        1       a
7  3     4        2       d
8  3     3        3       c
9  3     5        4       b
```

When I plot them, there is something I do not understand:

```
library(dplyr) 
dats$filling <- reorder(dats$filling, -dats$ordering)

ggplot(dats,aes(x = id,
                y = value,
                fill = filling)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend("ordering"))
```

[image]

The second and the third id are not properly ordered, I should have the order of the original dataset.

Comment: Yes, the same in the data as ordered: look at the last table, you can find for the 1 column abc, the second ba, the third adcb, as stated in the "ordering" column, that orders each id from the smallest to the bigger value of itself.

Comment: Also, your question in some ways is better than the dupe, because it provides reproducible data. I would recommend editing your question to make the goal clear. Edit out the distracting bit of doing the `reorder` inline, and state the goal clearly, something like *"I want each stack ordered independently, based on the `ordering` column*" and maybe someone will come along with a clearer answer. If you make those edits (and get or post an answer), I'd be tempted to close the other Q as a dupe of this one because this one will be a much better question.

Comment: I got another solution, using only `ggplot2` and a single `geom_bar`. Will be happy to share here if the question gets reopened.

Comment: @JuliusVainora reopened. And as discussed above marked the other question as a dupe of this one as this one has reproducible data and already one better answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use separate `geom_bar`s, you can make the orders different.

```
dats %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = reorder(filling,-ordering))) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", data = dats %>% filter(id == 1)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", data = dats %>% filter(id == 2)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack", data = dats %>% filter(id == 3)) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend("ordering"))
```

[image]

More generally:

```
bars <- map(unique(dats$id)
            , ~geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack"
                       , data = dats %>% filter(id == .x)))

dats %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = reorder(filling,-ordering))) + 
    bars +
    guides(fill=guide_legend("ordering"))
```

Comment: That's was one of the option, but this is not a real dataset, and I'd like to have a solution that fits for every dataset. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: I see. You can generate all the separate bars at once using `map`. I edited my answer to show how.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that, in your case, different bars should use the same values (levels) of `filling` in a different order. This conflicts with the way `ggplot` works: taking the factor levels (which already have a certain order) and applying them in the same way for each bar.

A workaround then is... To create many factor levels.

```
ggplot(dats, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = interaction(-ordering, id))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")
```

[image]

This one now is too "generous" by being too detailed. However, what we can do now is to deal with the legend and the different colors:

```
dats <- arrange(dats, id, -ordering)
aux <- with(dats, match(sort(unique(filling)), filling))
ggplot(dats, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = interaction(-ordering, id))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_manual("Ordering", values = scales::hue_pal()(4)[dats$filling],
                    labels = with(dats, filling[aux]), 
                    breaks = with(dats, interaction(-ordering, id)[aux]))
```

[image]

Here I first rearrange the rows of `dats` as to avoid doing that later. Then `aux` is an auxiliary vector

```
aux
# [1] 3 2 1 8
```

giving arbitrary positions (one for each) where levels `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` (in this order) appear in `dats`, which again is useful later. Then I simply set corresponding scale values, labels, and breaks... Lastly, I use `scales::hue_pal` to recover the original color palette.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the easiest approach would be to use the `group` aes to set the order of the stacked bars. To this end

1. arrange your dataset in the desired order (what you already did)
2. create a helper column as the interaction of `id` and `ordering`
3. convert this helper column to a `factor` with the order set as in the data using e.g. `forcats::fct_inorder`
4. finally, map the helper column on the `group` aes.

Note: Additionally I used `position_stack(reverse = TRUE)` to reverse the order of the stack and `guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)` to reverse the order in the legend.

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

dats <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  value = c(9, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 5),
  ordering = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4),
  filling = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "b")
) %>%
  arrange(id, ordering) |>
  mutate(
    id_ordering = paste(id, ordering, sep = "_"),
    id_ordering = forcats::fct_inorder(id_ordering)
  )

ggplot(dats, aes(
  x = id,
  y = value,
  fill = filling,
  group = id_ordering
)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  labs(fill = "ordering") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is that the element `filling = d` only appears in the third group with a low value. One solution, could be to fill non-present values with 0:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
dats <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                   value = c(9,6,4,0,5,6,0,0,4,3,4,5),
                   ordering = c(1,2,3,5,2,3,5,5,1,3,2,4),
                   filling = c('a','b','c','d','b','a','c','d','a','c','d','b')) %>% arrange(id,ordering)


ggplot(dats,aes(x = id,
                y = value,
                fill = reorder(filling,-ordering))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend("ordering"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, but the result should be first column abc, second, ba, third, adcb (from the bottom).