# reorder each facet ascending for a ggplot stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- read.table(text = "A B C
                          1   23  234 324
                          2   34  534 12
                          3   56  324 124
                          4   34  234 124
                          5   123 534 654",
                  sep = "", 
                  header = TRUE) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(ind = as.factor(rep(1:5)), 
         perc = value / sum(value))

ggplot(dat, aes(variable, perc, fill = ind)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  facet_grid(~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image: stacked bar]

The code above creates the stacked bar facet that you also see above. The `ind` portions of each bar graph are ordered the same as they are displayed on the legend.

I prefer that each `ind` portion is instead put in ascending (or descending) order. I usually accomplish this thanks to @dgrtwo and the [reorder_within](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R) function.

```
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}
```

But - using it in my case breaks apart the stacked bar graph above, into this exploded plot below. How do I keep the stacked bar graph, and order each `ind` ascending or descending?

*Note - This is likely not a duplicate of several other "reorder within facets" questions. I have not been able to find a question that deals with stacked bar graphs, and the issue I describe above.*

```
ggplot(dat, 
       aes(reorder_within(ind, value, variable), perc, fill = ind)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  facet_grid(~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image: stacked bar ascending]

Comment: Am I right that this one is a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53596262/1320535

Comment: @Julius Vainora thanks, that's close but it's missing the faceting. Which I need in my case.

Comment: I tried my solution from that question and it seems to work with faceting as well.

Comment: @Julius Vainora that's great! do you mind pasting your code as the answer then? I'm reading your prior answer now and it'll take a little time for me to incorporate it with faceting, and getting all the syntax right. Or do I just close this question? Seems like it may be useful to others.

Comment: Actually that question isn't an exact duplicate as (at least) it already has the needed order, while your data doesn't. So, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some manipulations [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598064/1320535) becomes

```
dat <- dat %>% arrange(variable, -perc) %>% mutate(ordering = row_number())
aux <- with(dat, match(sort(unique(ind)), ind))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = variable, y = perc, fill = interaction(-ordering, variable))) + 
  geom_col() + facet_grid(~ variable, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_fill_manual("ind", values = scales::hue_pal()(5)[dat$ind],
                    labels = with(dat, ind[aux]), 
                    breaks = with(dat, interaction(-ordering, variable)[aux])) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

Comparing to the linked answer, I primarily sorted the rows and added `ordering`. As to recover the default color palette, I also used `hue_pal` from `scales`. This was needed due to using `scale_fill_manual`, in which case colors need to be provided manually.

Comment: how do I keep the original color scheme?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as of tidyverse_1.3.1, the left-hand bar is correct, but the other two bars are all gray.